# overriding java serialisation mismatch

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have the problem of serialized objects having a mismatching serialversionuids..
Here is my scenario...

Version 1.
Class A extends Class B, both implement serializable, Class B **DOES NOT HAVE A SERIAL UID**

Version 2.
Class A extends Class B, both implement serializable, Class B *NOW HAS A SERIAL UID**, CLASS A's serialuid is same as that of version 1.

sadly i dont have access to the java sources, so i checked here and on other sites and found a workaround by overriding the readclassdescriptor of my objectinputstream and using that to read the objects.. however, i followed the example to the letter but my code still reports that the serialversionuids (of class B) still do not match.. i even tried another solution where i "inject" the Class B version 2's serialversionuid into Class B v1's data and then read using objectinputstream but i can't find the serialversionuid in the file where Class B v1's objects are persisted (using a hex viewer/editor) .. any ideas how i can overcome this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would set the serialVersionUID to 1 and when you get your error message like

```
serialVersionUID=-1023774639622504485 local class serialVersionUID=1
```

you know that if you change your serialVersionUID to `-1023774639622504485`L or what ever it is it will match what you have currently. This will allow you to get past the uid check.

Comment: well i dont have access to the source files of both classes